Find the second smallest prime factor of $\frac{1^3+1}{1+1}+\frac{2^3+1}{2+1}+\frac{3^3+1}{3+1}+...+\frac{726^3+1}{726+1}$
I've been practicing several contest math questions in preparation for an upcoming competition. I came across this question:
Determine the second smallest prime factor of $\frac{1^3+1}{1+1}+\frac{2^3+1}{2+1}+\frac{3^3+1}{3+1}+...+\frac{726^3+1}{726+1}$
First of all, I tried coming up with a general formula for this series. I evaluated the first $4$ terms, which was $1$, $3$, $7$ and $13$. Each term differs the next by even numbers $2$, $4$ and $6$. I simplified the expression $a + (a+r)+(a+3r)+(a+6r)...$, where $a$ is the first term (in this case is $1$) and $r$ is the common difference (in this case is $2$) into:
$$n+\frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{3}$$
using the tetrahedral numbers formula, and where $n$ is the number of terms. From this, I could technically plug in $n=726$ and evaluate, but this will require both lengthy calculation and a very large number, which I could very well not know how to find the prime factors of. I won't have access to a calculator in a contest.
Is there a more elegant way to solve this question? Thank you!

Since $726=2\times 3\times 11^2$, you can confirm $2$ is the smallest prime factor of $n+\frac{n(n-1)(n+1)}{3}$. Next, check whether or not the next few smallest primes are factors, without multiplying everything out first, to get what the second smallest prime factor is. This is something I was able to do relatively easily without a calculator.

I was just comparing your comment with the answer below, it seems that I was just about to solve it. Thank you for validating my method!

$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k=1}^{726} \frac{k^3+1}{k+1} & =\sum_{k=1}^{726}\left(k^2-k+1\right) \\
& =\sum_{k=1}^{726} k^2-\sum_{k=1}^{726} k+726 \\
& =\frac{726}{6}(727)(1453)-\frac{726}{2}(727)+726 \\
& =2^2\times 31888219\end{aligned}
$$
Since $31888219$ is not divisible by $3, 5$ and $7$ but divisible by $11$, therefore the second smallest prime factor is $11$.
Wish it helps.

A Better way to simplify this is to factorize:
$r^3+1 = (r+1)(r^2-r+1)$
Now we get the general term as
$ r^2-r+1 $
We now need to calculate the summation of this series to 726 terms.
$\sum_{r=1}^{786} (r^2-r+1)$
Breaking this into 3 different summations, we get
$\sum_{r=1}^{n} (r^2) - \sum_{r=1}^{n} (r) + \sum_{r=1}^{n} (1)$
Calculating each term separately, we get
$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} - \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + n$
Taking $n$ common and simplifying gets us to
$\frac{(n)(2n^2+6n-2)}{6}$
Putting $n$=726 , we get
$121*2(n^2+3n-1)$
Note that, Since $2$ and $11$ are already factors, now we have an upper-bound, So now we just need to check the divisibility of the other  part by $3,5,7$
Divisibility by $3$->
Since n is divisible by $3$, $ n^2+3n$ will also be divisible by $3$; this implies that $ n^2+3n-1$ is not divisible by $3$.
Divisibility by $5$->
You can easily check the number's last digit: $6+8-1$(Last digits) = $3$. Hence, it is also not divisible by $5$.
Divisibility by $7$->
Remainder given on dividing $726^2$ by $7$ is $4$($(721+5)^2$ gives $25$ and $25$ gives $4$)
The remainder given by $726$ on dividing by $7$ is $5$
So the Net remainder is $4+3*5-1=18$ implies the remainder is $4$i.e. it is also not divisible by $7$.
Hence the 2nd smallest prime factor of the sum is 11.

We can telescope the sum as follows:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{726} \frac{n^3+1}{n+1} &= \sum_{n=1}^{726} (n^2-n+1)
\\
&= 726 - \frac{726}3 + \frac13\sum_{n=1}^{726} [n^3 - (n-1)^3]
\\
&= 242 \times ( 2 + 726^2 )
\\
&= 2^2 \times 11^2 \times (1 + 2\times 3^2 \times 11^4).
\end{align}
Obviously, the quantity inside parentheses is not divisible by $2$ or $3$. It is also easy to check that
\begin{align}
&2 \times 3^2 \times 11^4 = 2 \times (-1) \times 1 = 3 \mod 5,
\\
&2 \times 3^2 \times 11^4 = 2 \times 2 \times 4^4 = 2^4 = 2 \mod 7,
\end{align}
so the quantity in parentheses is not divisible by $5$ or $7$ either. Therefore, the second smallest prime factor is $11$.

Since $7-2+6=11$, the number $726$ passes the divisibility test for $11$, and so does your entire formula which has no denominator divisible by $11$. Also the formula is even for even $n$.
So the second smallest prime factor must be in $\{3,5,7,11\}$. Since $726$ is divisible by $3$ but not by $9$, the term $n(n+1)(n-1)/3$ isn't divisible by $3$ and that possibility is eliminated. Simple modular arithmetic computations, which I leave for the reader, reveal that the formula has nonzero residue $\bmod 5$ and $\bmod 7$, so $11$ which was proven to be a factor at the outset is the survivor.
